# Sql query using length and left functions

Tags: sql

How to write query for below statement...

```
if length(ab>=8) than left(ab,8) else empty
```

Comment: `ab>=8` is a boolean expression, and returns the values TRUE or FALSE (or perhaps null.) Length on a boolean value makes no sense.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images, no links.) [mcve]

Comment: Take ab as one column name and it contains some values if value length is >8  I want to print just 8 characters from left

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ab varchar(50) = '123456789' 

IF LEN(@ab) >= 8    -- replace @ab by your variable or column name
       SELECT LEFT(@ab,  8);
ELSE 
       SELECT '';
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: This is for SQL Server